# Heroku build script error: failed to push some refs

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, npm

I do everything as in the heroku documentation.
What i need to do?

This is my heroku log

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! applicationreact@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the applicationreact@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.LoxFs/_logs/2019-06-11T16_28_34_410Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! applicationreact@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild: `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the applicationreact@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.LoxFs/_logs/2019-06-11T16_28_34_426Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed

       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys

       If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
       https://help.heroku.com/

       Love,
       Heroku

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

I try to do all from [this page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys).
`heroku buildpacks:set heroku/nodejs`
 I was specifying a node and npm version
I was checking my .gitignore

Comment: Error on console
`! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/tranquil-everglades-33541.git'`

Comment: I paste all what i have ^^. Idk where is this folder `/tmp/npmcache.LoxFs/_logs/2019-06-11T16_28_34_426Z-debug.log`